# not able to update using Update-AzTableRow with quotes

Tags: powershell, azure-table-storage

I have the following powershell script in order to update a value in table storage:

```
    [string]$filter = `
    [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery]::GenerateFilterCondition("Query",`
    [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.QueryComparisons]::Equal,"(Type = 'FTE')")
    
    $user = Get-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -customFilter $filter

    # Change the entity.
    $user.Query = "[{"filter":"(Type = 'FTE')"}]" // I need to include all these double quotes, single quotes

    $user | Update-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable
```

I see this error: Unexpected token 'filter":"' in expression or statement. How do I resolve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an aside: you don't need explicit line continuations (via `` ` `` at the very end of a line) if the line at hand *isn't* syntactically a complete statement by itself. In other words: in your code, only the `Get-AzTableRow` call requires it.

Your main problem is that **you're trying to embed `"` chars. inside a `"..."` string *without escaping***, which causes your problem.

To **escape `"` chars.** inside an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), **use `` `" ``** (or `""`):

Therefore:

```
$user.Query = "[{`"filter`":`"(Type = 'FTE')`"}]"
```

See also: The conceptual [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules) help topic.